# HOA bank account

Tags: banking

An HOA's property manager has had complete control over the operations account and now that they are departing want to close the account and send us a check.  The account has value in the sense that we paid for services (coupons) to collect monthly checks.

That being said, the property manager claims that the account is tied to her SSN and is the reason for closing the account.  I do not think that this is true: the bank initially indicated that the account is tied to the HOA EIN.  However, the bank is now not wanting to get in the middle of a conflict.

Is there any rules or line of reasoning to conclude that the account is not tied to the SSN?